# Create plots in a loop using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to generate 250 plots with the same view.

My example data set:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("john","alex","mike","dennis","alex"),
             expenses = c("10","12","15","8","2"),
             type = c("food","rent","rent","food","food"))
```

I would like bar plots with the expenses for every name in a single plot. The plot for "alex" will look like:

```
selected.name <- "alex"
df1 <- subset(df, name == selected.name)
ggplot(data = df1, aes(type, expenses)) + geom_bar()
```

Now I want to use a loop that plots the same plot for every name in the df. I have tried to use a for loop that runs the plot code above as a source file. But I can't pass the name variable to the source file so that it plots the graph for every name. Now I only get one graph out of the for loop.

Comment: please specify your question a little more. is your problem that you only get 1 window with 1 graph? than `x11()` could be the solution. if you want to save pdfs then use `pdf(file)` `print(ggplot(...)` `dev.off()`....

Comment: Hi Seb,  thanks for the reply. I want create a plot like the plot I created for the name alex for every other name in df. Without having to manually type in the names. Because in the real data there are 250 names. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Seb, I'd go for ggsave instead of pdf().

Comment: does [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6232718/471093) help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your orignal question. To do this using standard R:

```
doPlot = function(sel_name) {
   dum = subset(df, name == sel_name)
   ggobj = ggplot(data = dum, aes(type, expenses)) + geom_bar()
   print(ggobj)
   ggsave(sprintf("%s.pdf", sel_name))
}
lapply(unique(df$name), doPlot)
```

In this way you end up with a large number of pdf files called Adam.pdf etc. You could then use pdftk (pdf tool kit) to cat the files together in one document. I would still prefer, a better solution using e.g. facetting or a different type of plot.

Wouldn't it be much better to use facetting? Given your example the code would be:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(type, expenses)) + 
   geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~name)
```

which leads to the following plot:

[image]

Maybe for 250 names and more variables, this might be a problem. But I'd look at facetting nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is a nice feature. It handy to compare the plots. In the real df there are 250 names and 12 expenses variables. This will generate a very complex plot. I am building a reporting tool that generates all kind of KPIs per employee. And we don't make an comparisons in this report. That why I need all individual plots. The report in generated with Latex/R sweave.

Comment: I added a solution with individual plots in separate pdf files to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Paul, this works perfect for me right now. I can adept the functions further to my needs.

Comment: The key is to have print(ggobj) to get the side effect of plot being displayed, otherwise, there will be no plot displayed.

Answer (score 2):

A collegue just pointed out that using subset in a function is a very bad idea. See `?subset()` for more info. So I adapted the anwser of Paul Hiemstra and replaced the subset.

```
doPlot = function(sel_name) {
   dum <- df[df$name == sel_name,]
   ggobj = ggplot(data = dum, aes(type, expenses)) + geom_bar()
   print(ggobj)
   ggsave(sprintf("%s.pdf", sel_name))
}
lapply(unique(df$name), doPlot)
```